# Using an alias in where clause with a group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Using a SQL query, I am trying to find the number of users that have had page views greater than 5 in a given month.

What I have so far is exactly the above except, I can't add the condition of a minimum of 5 page views. It is currently showing the number of users who have had at least 1 page view in a given month.

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(analytics.date),'/',YEAR(analytics.date)) AS DATE, 
       COUNT(analytics.id) AS views, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS num_users
FROM users
     LEFT JOIN analytics ON users.id = analytics.user_id
WHERE users.banned = 0 
      AND analytics.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(analytics.date), MONTH(analytics.date)
```

I tried adding `AND views > 5` in the where clause but that didn't work as I get an unknown column.

I don't think a `HAVING` clause will work as this is applied after the `GROUP BY` and I need to find individual users who have had more than 5 page views.

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: Five views in one month or five views overall?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The user has to have at least 5 page views, then I want a count of all these users for a given month.

Comment: You **need** the `HAVING` clause. If you need user ids you must add it to SELECT and GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @SalmanA: incorrect, since it's asking about whether a user in general has more than 5 views, not just 5 views within the given grouping.

Comment: @siride then you add user id to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @SalmanA: then the groups wouldn't be for months, but for users and months. It changes the output structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a subquery for this, since you're selecting which users feed into the `GROUP BY`. Here, we do a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to ask for each row if the user has at least five entries in the `analytics` table.

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(analytics.date),'/',YEAR(analytics.date)) AS DATE, 
COUNT(analytics.id) AS views, 
COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS num_users
FROM users
LEFT JOIN analytics ON users.id = analytics.user_id
WHERE users.banned = 0 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM analytics AS a WHERE a.user_id = users.id) > 5
AND analytics.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(analytics.date), MONTH(analytics.date)
```

If you want there to be more than 5 views for the user in the given month, then you have to modify your query and you'll need to use an inner join:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(analytics.date),'/',YEAR(analytics.date)) AS DATE, 
COUNT(analytics.id) AS views, 
COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS num_users
FROM users
JOIN analytics ON users.id = analytics.user_id
WHERE users.banned = 0 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM analytics AS a WHERE a.user_id = users.id AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM a.date) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM analytics.date)) > 5
AND analytics.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(analytics.date), MONTH(analytics.date)
```

Comment: but where the filter for views > 5?

Comment: @Piyush: I swear I originally read it as `> 0`. I'll remove the inner join stuff. The subquery part still works fine.

Comment: Marking this as thw answer since you were the first to reply, both you and Gordon had the same answer that works for me. Query is slow though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If this is your requirement, then you need to aggregate twice, once at the user level and second at the analytics level. Or, use a subquery in the `where` clause.  Here is what you may need:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(a.date),'/',YEAR(a.date)) AS DATE, 
       COUNT(a.id) AS views, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS num_users
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     analytics a
     ON u.id = a.user_id
WHERE u.banned = 0 AND a.id IS NOT NULL AND
      5 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM analytics a2 WHERE a2.user_id = u.userid)
GROUP BY YEAR(a.date), MONTH(a.date);
```

This uses the overall count for the limit.

EDIT:  TO speed the subquery, be sure you have an index on `analytis(user_id, date)`.

Comment: I think in the sub-query I need to include another condition, to limit the count of views to be this month and not all time. `AND MONTH(a.date) = MONTH(a2.date)`, testing it now, its getting confusing!

Comment: @Abs . . .  If the limit is 5 views in a month, then you need to include those conditions in the subquery.  If the limit is 5 views over all time, then you don't need to include that logic.

Comment: I have added those conditions to the sub-query and waiting for the result. It is taking a long long time. This sub-query has slowed things down. If it takes longer, I will go ahead and index the date column! The analytics table has millions of rows.